# Is there an analog to pg_notify that allows (un)listening from a dynamically generated channel name?

Tags: postgresql

I am able to do something like the following in my application:

```
PERFORM pg_notify((
  SELECT CONCAT('some_functional_prefix_', notify_key)
  FROM some_table
  WHERE lookup_key = my_lookup_key
), '');
```

This way, I can notify e.g. specific clients (designated by `notify_key`) which are listening for potentially many types of updates (designated by `some_functional_prefix_`).

However, there doesn't appear to be a listen/unlisten analog that allows me to build my desired channel name via string concatenation. My clients know their keys, so they can build channel names before interacting with the database easily enough, but it would be much cleaner in the current design to build channel names in PL/pgSQL. Is this possible?

If it makes any difference, I'm using postgres current as of this writing, which is v13.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use dynamic SQL, by building a LISTEN/UNLISTEN command string, and passing that string to EXECUTE.  Using 'format' is useful for constructing the string if you don't what all characters it might contain.

```
text_var='something';
execute format('LISTEN %I',text_var);
```

Comment: I'll add per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT that %I treats the value as a SQL identifier, which is why this works. Thanks, @jjanes